# Error Installing Ruby 3.2.2 with RVM on macOS: 'username_completion_function' undeclared

Tags: ruby, macos, compilation, rvm

I'm encountering an issue while trying to install Ruby 3.2.2 using RVM on my Mac (macOS version 14.1). The installation fails with an error related to `readline`. Here is the relevant error message from the log file:

`readline.c:1903:37: error: use of undeclared identifier 'username_completion_function'; did you mean 'rl_username_completion_function'`

console outpout:
`Error running '__rvm_make -j12',
please read /Users/guillaumemarenghi/.rvm/log/1704748683_ruby-3.2.2/make.log

There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.`

I have already attempted the following approaches, but none have resolved the issue:

1. Updated Homebrew and reinstalled `openssl` and `readline`.
2. Installed Ruby specifying the paths to `openssl` explicitly.
3. Cleaned up the RVM environment and retried.

Despite these attempts, the error persists. I am looking for suggestions or alternative solutions to address this issue. Here are some additional details that might be helpful:

- macOS Version: Sonoma 14.1
- RVM Version: 1.29.12

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I strongly recommend rbenv over rvm on Mac.